# How to delete data from combobox if it's present in the database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox

I have a situation where I have to assign room numbers to the customers and delete the assigned room numbers from the list.

I think I will be done by searching the table of the database. And if the program finds any assigned room number in the database, then it deletes it from the combobox.

I am using this code:

```
con.Open();

string selectSQL = "SELECT Room_Number FROM Reservation WHERE Reservation_ID > 0";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);

SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rd.Read())
{
    string RoomNumber = rd.GetString(0);

    foreach (string NumberOfRoom in RoomNumber)
    {
        if (NumberOfRoom == cbRoomNumber.Text)
        {
            cbRoomNumber. 
        }
    }
}

rd.Close();
con.Close();
```

But I don't know what to do next.

Please any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: What's the PK in Reservation table? Is `Reservation_ID`?

Comment: This code has holes. Big ones. `rd.GetString(0)` gives you _one_ Room_Number - `foreach` ing over it's chars would only make sense if you have less then 10 rooms total and store a reservation of room 1 to 3 in one entrxy of Reservation and put it in as `"123"`.  A combobox holds mutliple items , the `Text` shows you only the currently selected one. You would need to manipulate the Enumeration of possible values behind your combobox - and this (the model / xaml / observableCollenction is not shown. Your sql lacks `using` blocks which is the preferred way of dealing with IDisposables, etc.

Comment: Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @daniel.shih Yes!

Comment: You may find `Reservation_ID` on checkBox and delele by `Reservation_ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to do this

```
if (NumberOfRoom == cbRoomNumber.Text)
    {
       cbRoomNumber.Items.Remove(NumberOfRoom)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix DB querying logic with whatever happens outside. What you really need is some kind of `RoomRepository` such that you could do `roomRepo.IsFree(any_parameter_goes_here)`. So: 
`if (roomRepo.IsFree(...)) { }` gives you a nice way to alter execution at the given point without hardcoding SQL into method implementation.

Not quite sure my answer is what you were seeking for, but that's certainly a good starting point toward much more clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Everybody. I made the Logic.
Here it is.

```
 con.Open();

        string selectSQLR = "SELECT Room_Number FROM Reservation where Reservation_ID > 0";

        SqlCommand cmdR = new SqlCommand(selectSQLR, con);
        SqlDataReader rdR;
        rdR = cmdR.ExecuteReader();

          while (rdR.Read())
            {
                string RoomNumber = rdR.GetString(0);

                cbRoomNumber.Items.Remove(RoomNumber);
            }

        rdR.Close();
        con.Close();
```